# Replace string of text in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace string of text and I get  `The regular expression pattern  is not valid.`

This is to be able to change a policy using LGPO

```
$TextToBeReplaced="Computer`r`nSOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard`r`nDeployConfigCIPolicy`r`nDWORD:1`r`n`r`nComputer`r`nSOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard`r`nConfigCIPolicyFilePath`r`nSZ:C:\\WL\\politicas\\DeviceGuardPolicy.bin"

$NewText="Computer`r`nSOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard`r`nDeployConfigCIPolicy`r`nDELETE`r`n`r`nComputer`r`nSOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard`r`nConfigCIPolicyFilePath`r`nDELETE"

((Get-Content -path $LGPOTxt -Raw) -replace $TextToBeReplaced,$NewText) | Set-Content -Path $LGPOTxt
```

LGPO.txt contains this what I have to change is this string for the other in order to apply the new LGPO policy

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
; PARSING Computer POLICY
; Source file:  C:\WL\LGPO\LGPOBackUp\DomainSysvol\GPO\Machine\registry.pol

Computer
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard
DeployConfigCIPolicy
DWORD:1

Computer
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard
ConfigCIPolicyFilePath
SZ:C:\\WL\\politicas\\DeviceGuardPolicy.bin

; PARSING COMPLETED.
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-with-regular-expressions) treats replacement text as regular expression.

```
<input> -replace <regular-expression>, <substitute>
```

Instead, you could [use `replace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#definition) on the string object.

```
(Get-Content -path $LGPOTxt -Raw).replace($TextToBeReplaced, $NewText) | Set-Content -Path $LGPOTxt
```

Comment: it doesnt changed it I applied just like you did

Comment: it seems is not working because is in several lines, but i want to keep that text structure

Comment: Can you update the question with sample `$LGPOTxt` file content?

Comment: I updated, adding the content of the txt

Comment: I solved, by adding 'r'n between new lines ill update it

Comment: @marcosagni98 Consider posting a complete answer of your own so that it can be marked as a solution :)

Comment: Nice, though it's worth noting that the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method is case-_sensitive_, unlike PowerShell's `-replace` operator. In _Windows PowerShell_, this cannot be helped; in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, there is a new overload that allows case-insensitivity as an opt-in.